# Change base class from System.Object to Framework.Object without deriving

Tags: c#, object

I'm making an own C# mscorlib for my project.
But is there a way to change the base class namespace.
Now I need:

`namespace System
{
    public class Object
    {
    }
}`

But I want:

`namespace Framework
{
    public class Object
    {
    }
}`

Is it possible in any way?

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't do that. The C# language specification explicitly states that the root of the class hierarchy is `System.Object`.

Building a replacement `mscorlib` is a pretty daunting task - are you really *sure* you want to do this?

Comment: Yes. I really want it.

Comment: Because I want to 'rebuild' some java things in C# that are in Java's code and since I can't edit mscorlib it's better to recreate it.

Comment: @user2199080: No, that's not better. The mscorlib has been built over years by highly skilled engineers. Is the name says, it contains the core libraries of the .NET framework. You are going the wrong way here. Maybe you can give a concrete example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I like the Java function names more and I think they're better, but I don't want java itself because in general C#'s debugger is better.

Comment: @user2199080: You can't be serious... Java and C# are different languages. Choose one and embrace it.

Comment: @user2199080: This is *absolutely* the wrong way to go about things. It sounds like you're probably reasonably new to C# and .NET - you should give up on the idea of rebuilding mscorlib *right now*. Get used to what .NET provides you - or find a better Java debugger if you actually want to be writing Java.